# Memory Leak Issues

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on Xcode8 and Swift3. While running the app I am using visual memory debugging. It shows me 3 memory issues on left hand side. Please let me know how can I resolve these memory issues?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really hard to tell you how to solve those issues without knowing the flow of your program. Plus, there are a lot of causes to memory issues, and it really depends on how you handled the instances of your object.

If you are not using ARC, the it means that you are responsible for releasing any object you created. Then you have to check in which stage did that object get leaked. As it stated there, it is a Dictionary that got leaked. So you have a clue on what specific object to check.

On the other hand, if you are using ARC, then you don't have to handle releasing of the objects that you created. But, it doesn't mean that you won't get any leaks. These are some possible causes that may cause a memory leak in your program even if using ARC:

- You set a strong reference to a parent in a child object. This causes a retain cycle.
- You set a strong reference to a delegate in an interface.
- You forgot to release an object when you do a toll-free bridging after transferring ownership.
- You forgot to set a weak reference to objects you passed in a block.

I hope this helps